# I need to rewrite this php line for php 5.2

Tags: php

getting an error here..

```
$mail = new SendGrid\Mail();
```

this line doesn't work in php 5.2, i have read the slash comes in after php 5.3.

how can i fix this to be compatible with php 5.2?

Thank you.

Comment: You will have to remove the classes' namespaces

Answer (score 3):

As long as `SendGrid\Mail` class is implemented using namespaces (php >= 5.3 feature) - there is no solution to only change the line

```
$mail = new SendGrid\Mail();
```

So you also need to modify that mail class and remove all php 5.2 incompatible things

Answer (score 1):

You will have to remove all [namespacing](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php). It is not supported at all before PHP 5.3 and will cause a parse error.

You will have to declare your classes without namespaces, and instantiate them without namespaces. This is potentially extremely non-trivial if your existing code uses any of the features that namespaces give you - e.g. duplicated class names.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using a PHP 5.3+ only compatible library (using the namespaces feature).

I'm afraid the only solutions would be to upgrade your installation, or use another library (or version of the library) not using the namespaces feature.

[Check here for a list of SendGrid PHP wrappers](http://docs.sendgrid.com/documentation/api-libraries/). You should find one compatible with PHP 5.2, for example [this one](https://github.com/alonbendavid/SendGrid-Newsletter-PHP-Library).

You can also try to modify your current library to remove namespace use, as suggested in other answers. Since the library size is quite small, you could give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

Include the file directly and

$mail = new Mail();

but probably there will be more problems then just this one, and it would be best to take another library.